# Self Sign .Net window based Application

Tags: .net

I am working on window based Application in .Net. I have created `exe` of my application and Now I want to Self Sign of `exe`. I do not want to purchase any certificate. Is there is any way to self sign `exe` in .Net ? I searched alot but did not find any way to self sign `exe`.

Comment: Do you want to sign with a strong name (The identity of the assembly and included type is certified) or sign the binary (you'll see a signature when looking the the file's properties)?

Answer (score 0):

.NET binaries can be signed in two different ways: with a strong name and regular Windows file signing. Self-signing should be used only for testing! Never ship self-signed files to your customers!

### Signing with a strong name

It's a way to certify the assembly identity and the containing types. (more info in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/create-use-strong-named))

You can sign with strong name by going in the Signing tab of your project properties if you're using Visual Studio. There's also a command line tool called "`al`", that you can find in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (`al /out:assemblyName moduleName /keyfile:keyfileName`).

For either approach you'll need a key file which you can generate using the sn.exe tool (found in the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt): `sn -k keyPair.snk`

### Windows binary signing

I couldn't find the official name, that's why I might refer to it in multiple ways; It's the digital signature you can see in the file property tab.

For this one you need `signtool.exe` which can be found in the Windows SDK or Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt (more info in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe)).

`signtool sign /f MyCert.pfx /p MyPassword /fd SHA256 MyApp.exe` would sign MyApp.exe using MyCert.pfx (which is password protected).

To generate a pfx certificate on Windows you could use openssl (there are other tools around, pick your favorite):

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem`  will generate pem files for a certificate valid for 3650 days and a private key.

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out MyCert.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem` will generate the pfx file.

I'm not a security expert, so please excuse any security issues or missing flags openssl commands might have. Certificate handling is a hard thing to do, this response is mostly focused on how you can sign your file after you have a certificate.